# Передача параметров в классах с наследованием

Tags: c++, передача-параметров

Всем привет! Вроде и простое, но не могу понять, как передавать параметры. Хочу передать по значению, хотя не важно как. Есть код. В классе `Rational`, с помощью конструктора с параметрами хочу сделать числитель и знаменатель, после чего результат их деления записываю в answer. В классе Number, родительском классе, существует метод `number_status`(). Хочу передать в значение `number` своё значение `answer`, чтобы при указании в 76 строке `Number_instance.number_status()`; мне выводило значение переменной number уже с новым параметром. Впрочем и не только в 76, чтобы после каждого моего класса, `Integer, Rational, Natural,` выводило ответ записанный в переменную `number`, которая объявлена в родительском классе Number. Подскажите, как мне это реализовать? Не выпрашиваю код, только советы по реализации.

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number {
public:
    double number = 8.2;

    void number_status() {
        cout << "Текущее значение number: " << number;
    }

    ~Number() {};
};

class Integer : public Number {
public:
    void integer_status() {
        cout << "Проверка числа на 'Целое ли число?': " << endl;
        if ((number - int(number)) != 0) {
            cout << "Число не является целым!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Это целое число!";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    ~Integer() {};
};

class Rational : public Number {
private:
    double chislitel;
    double znamenatel;
    double answer;
public:
    void rational_status(double c, double z) {
        chislitel = c; znamenatel = z;
        answer = c / z;
        cout << "Числитель = " << chislitel << endl;
        cout << "Знаменатель = " << znamenatel << endl;
        cout << "Результат деления: " << answer << endl;
        answer = number;
        void number_status();
    }

    ~Rational() {};
};

class Natural : public Number {
public:
    void natural_status() {
        cout << "\nПроверка числа на 'Натуральное ли число?': " << endl << endl;

    }

    ~Natural() {};
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    Number Number_instance;
    Integer Integer_instance;
    Rational Rational_instance;
    Natural Natural_instance;

    Number_instance.number_status();

    cout << "\t " << endl;
    Integer_instance.integer_status();

    cout << "\t " << endl;
    Rational_instance.rational_status(6, 2);
    Number_instance.number_status();

    cout << "\t " << endl;
    Natural_instance.natural_status();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//TODO
//Сделать в Rational через конструктор числитель и знаменатель и выводить результат деления
//Выводить в натуральном через конструктор число
//Сделать для Integer, Natural и Rational общий метод для вывода
```

Comment: Божественный код, особенно  public:
    double number = 8.2;, А вообще - попробуйте сначала как в книгах, есть класс А у него есть конструктор который просит что-то, от него унаследовался В который умеет выводить значение поля и т.д., А ваши деструкторы - это шик!!! Нафига они Вам пустыми? или удалите или напишите = default!

Comment: @Andrey, хорошо, хорошо, не бейте, исправлю, спасибо :)

Comment: конструкторы добавьте в код

Comment: @СергейСергеевич Скажите, а зачем Вы в методе **rational_status** сначала записываете в *answer* результат вычисления, а затем перетираете его значением поля *number*? И что значит внутри этого же метода строка **void number_status();**?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вы неверно используете полиморфизм.

Классы `Integer`, `Rational` и `Natural` публично наследуют класс `Number`. Это означает, что все публичные и защищённые (protected) члены базового класса `Number` доступны наследникам.

То есть класс `Integer` имеет публичный член `double number`, так как он унаследовал его от `Number`, равно как и метод `number_status()` тоже может быть вызван внутри наследника.

> Хочу передать в значение number своё значение answer

Не нужно его передавать. У каждого наследника есть свой `number`, который можно использовать непосредственно в наследнике.

Например:

```
#include <iostream>

class Operation
{
public:
    Operation() : result(0) {};
    unsigned result;

    void echo_result()
    {
        std::cout << "Текущее значение result: " << result << '\n';
    }
};

class Adder : public Operation
{
public:
    Adder(const unsigned a, const unsigned b) : a(a), b(b) {};

    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;

    void compute()
    {
        result = a + b;
    }
};

class Multiplier : public Operation
{
public:
    Multiplier(const unsigned a, const unsigned b) : a(a), b(b) {};

    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;

    void compute()
    {
        result = a * b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Adder adder(7, 3);
    adder.compute();
    adder.echo_result();

    Multiplier mul(7, 3);
    mul.compute();
    mul.echo_result();

    // Текущее значение result: 10
    // Текущее значение result: 21
}
```

Comment: Я так и не смог понять что нужно ТС, но  кажется это совсем не то, что ему нужно.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Из вот этих слов автора "чтобы при указании в 76 строке `Number_instance.number_status();` мне выводило значение переменной `number` уже с новым параметром." я понял, что он хочет выполнить операцию на `Rational_instance` и вывести результат с помощью базового класса: `Number_instance.number_status();`. То есть он хочет передать значение из унаследованного класса в родительский. Это то, что я понял из вопроса.

Comment: `const unsigned a, const unsigned b` серьезно? ：D

Comment: @ヒミコ, я не понимаю, что вы хотите этим сказать.